# what is the difference between overlay map type and layers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

From the google map v3 javascript api,I found this:

> **Overlay Map Types**
>
> Some map types are designed to work on top of existing map types. Such
>   map types may have transparent layers indicating points of interest,
>   or showing additional data to the user. (Google's traffic layer is an
>   example of such a map type.)

Which say that **Google's traffic layer is an example of such a map type**.

But the [traffic layer](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/layers.html#TrafficLayer) is intance of Layer in google map.

So I am confused with the concept.

Since we are build our own map library for offline use,so I want to refer google's concept and their idea.

Any one can give me more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layers and Overlays are not of the same type.

Layers can only be manipulated as a whole object. I guess google dont want you to mess with the information.

Layers thought of as a type of map type for selection, and are transparent. They are also sort of like the concept of an overlay as they are made of geometric shapes.

i think the concept is confusing because overlays, layers and the underlying map type are all things that in other systems (photoshop for example) would just be layers (that might be of different type (ie vector or raster).

Hope this helps.